# Find height attribute of svg rect with xpath

Tags: php, xpath, svg

There are multiple graph bars on page in next format:

```
<g transform="translate(4.139419078826904,136.6666717529297)" class="nv-bar positive" style="fill: rgb(228, 243, 217); stroke: rgb(228, 243, 217);">
<rect height="68.33333333333331" width="23.12365145228216" class="discreteBar"></rect>
</g>
```

I am trying to get a height attribute with xpath, but something is wrong.

I tried:

```
//g[contains(@class,'nv-bar') and contains(@class,'positive')]/rect/@height
```

and

```
//rect[@class='discreteBar']/@height
```

and combinations of above but still can't get it... please help!

Comment: Isn't there a namespace involved? Also, remove the `)` in the second XPath expression.

Comment: @choroba the code is directly from page, the whole group of `g` is wrapped with single `<svg class="graph-svg nvd3-svg" style="display: inline-block;"></svg>`

Comment: Works for me. Tested in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh).

Comment: @choroba hmm, I always used Xpath Helper extension in Chrome, I guess I need to look into more consistent alternatives...

Comment: @choroba trying in Javascript console of chrome with `$x` , but still nothing returned

Comment: Are you sure the SVG is in the current context (i.e. no iframe or similar)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122564/discussion-between-acidon-and-choroba).

Comment: I'm curious why did you ommited the svg root element. Isn't this happening because of that?